# Can you set envelope sender used by wp_mail?

Tags: wp-mail

Is it possible to change the envelope sender used by [`wp_mail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)?

So far I have tried setting [`headers`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/#Parameters), and the [`wp_mail_from`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail_from/) and [`wp_mail_from_name`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail_from_name/) filters.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please search the site, try something, (maybe) fail, [edit] your question with where you failed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can. There is several filters what you mentioned in your question. You can do it with [WP Mail SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) plugin. This plugin have multiple settings such as: Sender Name, Sender Email.  To get it to set the envelope sender as well, you have to turn on the "Return Path" option. This stuff working with using filters which you've mentioned.

You can also setup an external SMTP server which should be using to send all emails in WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

I have just written a plugin to do this as I didn't want to use SMTP or transnational email services https://wordpress.org/plugins/stop-wp-emails-going-to-spam/

The action hook you need is `phpmailer_init`  and from that you can set `$phpmailer->Sender`  ( the envelope sender )